# Is it safe to assume most weapons come with respective scabbards unless otherwise stated?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, weapons, treasure

A lot of the campaigns, usually the DM tells us that we find swords or something, but never said anything about finding the scabbard that would fit the blade of those swords. Is it safe for us to assume we find their scabbards anyway?

Comment: I've culled this question down because it was three questions at once: do weapons come with scabbards, tell me about scabbards, and tell me how we should handle not having scabbards. Those should be asked separately, but you should probably start with just this one.

Answer (score 28):

The *Player's Handbook* on Cost says

> This value is the weapon’s cost in gold pieces (gp) or silver pieces (sp). The cost includes miscellaneous gear that goes with the weapon, such as a scabbard for a sword or a quiver for arrows. (114)

This DM tends to assume when a creature has a weapon, there's also somehow a way for the creature to keep the weapon out of its own and others' ways yet ready enough so that the weapon can be drawn normally, be that a strap, scabbard, or cork atop a spear. Similarly, this DM assumes a looter (or a PC and often one and the same) that takes a weapon also takes the weapon's necessities with it when it loots the weapon without the looter needing to specify that it takes that stuff, and without me having to specify that stuff exists.

If it's somehow *important* that a weapon is *sans* scabbard (or cork or whatever), then I'd mention it during play, but otherwise convenience and playability, in this case, far overwhelm this DM's need to track all that.

Comment: This accounts for purchasing items, but I believe the question is about all forms of acquiring such weapons, including just finding them lying on the ground.

Comment: @SouthpawHare Fair enough. How's that? (The original statement was a holdover from the pre-edited question.)

Comment: Yeah, I think that's a bit more robust.

Comment: As a side note, this has always been one of those details that I actually *do* like to pay attention to as a DM, despite being a minor detail.  If someone picks up a random weapon, I like to at least throw out the question, "How are you stowing it?", and the answer is usually quickly resolved by them thinking to yoink the appropriate scabbard from the relevant NPC corpse.  Maybe it's just a weird OCD quirk of mine?

Comment: @SouthpawHare No, that's totally cool. Were a DM to require that of me as a player, though, I'd point to the [explorer's outfit description](http://dndsrd.net/goodsAndServices.html#explorers-outfit) and say, "Well, there goes my *first* scarf!" (Again, as an aside, I do have PCs track encumbrance (even, to some degree, coins) and have found that there are already enough weirdly weighty things in the game that adding *even more* — to me, anyway — seems excessive.)

Answer (score 9):

**It depends on the circumstances of how you find it.**

In some situations, it would make sense that a scabbard would be present, while in others, it does not.  This largely comes down to a common sense judgement call.

Some examples of when it probably makes sense that **there would be a scabbard:**

- The weapon is **taken from the dead corpse** of a warrior who was previously wearing it.
- The weapon is **sold in a store,** which may provide it as a convenience, or use it in an effort to display the weapon in a visually-appealing manner.

Some examples of when it probably makes sense that **there would *not* be a scabbard:**

- The weapon is **lying on the floor of a dungeon** where it has been sitting for many years (the scabbard, which is usually not magical even if the weapon is, would have rotted away).
- The weapon has **been flung away** or otherwise displaced a significant distance from its former wielder.
- The weapon is **embedded in a stone** for only the most worthy to pull.

Some examples of when it **could go either way:**

- The weapon is **part of a big pile** of assorted treasure in a dragon's hoard.
- The weapon is **equipment for a garrison,** pirate ship, etc. that keep some weapons on racks and shelves for the regulars, while the higher-ups may have their own equipment (and thus sheaths).

Whenever someone comes across a weapon, just take a moment to think about the circumstance.  If the issue seems too difficult to judge, just err on the side of having one for convenience.

Comment: You seem to be missing the two most common ways to acquire swords: Embedded in a stone, Giften by strange lady who lives in wetlands (prob, but not defn, a scabard being included). and Retrieved from being embedded in a stone (prob no scabard unless you count the stone)

Comment: @LyndonWhite I like it.  I'll include the stone one, thanks. =)